# libGDX TextureAtlas - providing master texture filename at runtime

Tags: libgdx

I would like to use identical .atlas file for multiple master texture files.
This can be easily achieved by having multiple almost identical .atlas files (with only difference being the first line with the texture file name), but it's not a nicest solution.

I was wondering if it's possible to provide the name of master texture file at runtime, during TextureAtlas object creation or later.
I took a quick look on the TextureAtlas code, but the API doesn't seem to allow that, at least not in an straightforward way.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some research it seems that the only way to achieve it is to extend TextureAtlas and then copy and modify the constructor code.
Currently the name of the texture file is obtained by simply reading the first line of the atlas file:

```
String line = reader.readLine();
                    if (line == null) break;
                    if (line.trim().length() == 0)
                        pageImage = null;
                    else if (pageImage == null) {
                        FileHandle file = imagesDir.child(line);
```

Instead of doing it this way the FileHandle would need to be created using a file name passed as an argument of a constructor.

In this situation I'm going to stick to the multiple atlas files :-)

Answer (score 0):

You can pass an images directory to the TextureAtlas constructor. I haven't tried it, but it seems like you could have your single .atlas file, then have the separate texture files in different directories.

From TextureAtlas...

```
public TextureAtlas (FileHandle packFile, FileHandle imagesDir) {
    this(packFile, imagesDir, false);
}

/** @param flip If true, all regions loaded will be flipped for use with a perspective where 0,0 is the upper left corner. */
public TextureAtlas (FileHandle packFile, FileHandle imagesDir, boolean flip) {
    this(new TextureAtlasData(packFile, imagesDir, flip));
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's not what I'm looking for. This solution replaces multiple atlas files with multiple folders with a single file in each of them, which is not really an improvement. I've done some research today and there's no way I can achieve what I want simply using the API. The only way I found is modifying the constructor code and I wrote an answer about it. However I'm not going to implement this solution.

Comment: Fair enough. I'd argue it is an improvement on multiple atlas files though, as you no longer have the maintenance headache of maintaining multiple almost identical atlas files. Still, it's your project.

Comment: Generally you're right, maintenance would be easier. However these particular files won't really be a subject to change. Still I may use your solution somewhere else, so thanks for pointing me to it!